# PHP 2d array question

Tags: php

So i have a 2 dimensional array that is used over several pages (session)

```
            $_SESSION ["Table"][$_SESSION ["count"]] [0] = $filename;
            $_SESSION ["Table"][$_SESSION ["count"]] [1] = $size;
            $_SESSION ["Table"][$_SESSION ["count"]] [2] = $floor;
            $_SESSION ["Table"][$_SESSION ["count"]] [3] = $phone;
            $_SESSION ["Table"][$_SESSION ["count"]] [4] = $network;
            $_SESSION ["Table"][$_SESSION ["count"]] [5] = $totalprice;
```

This is used with a form so i can give in multiple input wich gets stored.

But my question is how exactly can i calculate the AVERAGE of  $total price of all given in results?

Meaning for example i have 5 rows so this would mean 5 total prices.  How exactly can i acces this value and count everything up / 5? This will happen in a other page so i would like to use sessions for this. /5 simply by count($_Session["table"]) , but really not sure about the other values.

Kind Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not sure'? Have you tried actually `count()`ing yet and seeing if it works?

Comment: Well basicly everything works exept for a new page. I basicly wanne show the row with the largest $totalprice and also display the average of the totalprice$ , just a page that adds more detailed information.

Comment: There are no 2D arrays in PHP; there are nested arrays. There's a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate through an array, you can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
$totalPrice = 0;
$totalItems = count( $_SESSION['Table'] );
foreach( $_SESSION['Table'] as $result ) {
    $totalPrice += $result[4];
}
echo $totalPrice / $totalItems;
```

Though i'm not quite getting your data structure - I have a feeling this might be a work around for a deeper problem.

Comment: +1 I share your sentiments about a possible 'deeper problem'.